# Triglyceride using chemfig

Tags: graphics, chemfig

I can't seem to replicate this triglyceride structure in LaTex, I can connect the carbon atom with a 270 degree angle [6], but I can't figure out how to add the hydrogen on the left of the carbon. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Please show a compilable minimal working example that demonstrates what you tried so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
\chemfig[atom sep=2em]{H-C(-[2,2]C(-[4]H_2)-O-C(=[2]O)-R_1)(-[6,2]C(-[4]H_2)-O-C(=[2]O)-R_3)-O-C(=[2]O)-R_2}
\end{document}
```

[image]